# How to get output as csv file in selenium python

Tags: python

I copied some of the text from the website using selenium, Now i need to output the data as CSV file how can i do it.

```
jTitle = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='vjs-jobtitle']").text


myFile = open('output.csv', 'w')
with myFile:
    writer = csv.writer(myFile)
    writer.writerow(jTitle)
```

i got the output file but, the each character entered into different column.Please check the image.

[image]

Comment: You should have went through the documentation of the module "csv", use this instead : writer.writerow([jTitle])

Comment: This has nothing to do with Selenium. Removed Selenium-related tags. You need to add a tag for whatever CSV library you are using.

Answer (score 2):

To write a text value on `CSV` file just use

```
myFile.write("text val")
```

Here is the code.

```
jTitle = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='vjs-jobtitle']").text
myFile = open('output.csv', 'w')
myFile.write(jTitle)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response here, but I would like to ask how can we control the location of the output. For example, if we want to write the word "HR" on [10, 10], how can we do so?